# How to programmatically check whether the mobile phone is currently charging or is on battery?

Tags: api, mobile-phones, power-management

do the mobile phones have an API function, or something similar, that could be called by a phone application to determine whether the phone is currently charging or is on battery?

I'm guessing that if there is such a function, it would likely have a different name on each mobile OS, so if anybody could name those function names, and the OS for each, that would be great.

many thx

Answer (score 0):

Nokia's implementation of Java ME has an API function to [check the battery level](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/CS001201_-_Checking_battery_level_in_Java_ME).
More generally, Java ME has the "[Sensor API](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_use_sensors_in_Java_ME)" (which is highly implementation-specific) that [exposes sensors](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_get_information_about_sensors_in_Java_ME) such as the charger state, accelerometer(s), etc.

Answer (score 0):

On the **RIM** **BlackBerry** line of devices, this can be done by using the **net.rim.device.api.system.DeviceInfo** class; specifically, the **getBatteryStatus()** static method of that class which returns a bitfield of flags related to the battery state on the device. The bitfield contains various flags that indicate whether the device is being charged or is running on battery power (among other things).